# How to send successful message to the caller method?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a method that is used to save a contact form in database as following, If something goes wrong it throws an exception that will be sent back to the caller of this method.

I am not sure if what I am doing is the best way assure the caller of this method that everything went well.

```
public boolean saveContact(Contact contact)throws HibernateException{  
    currentSession().save(contact);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is the right method. Caller can only decide the corrective action against based on exception.

Comment: @SivaKumar do you mean I should send a customSuccessException? or just return true for success?

Comment: @DanielNewtown the method you are using ie sending booean is good way..

Comment: I don't understand the need for the boolean return. If everything went ok, there is no exception, so you know it is good if you got no exception. A boolean would indicate that there are 2 possible outcomes: true and false. Here you will never return false, so there is no need for the boolean.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe is there any case that I would need to?

Comment: I don't see it. Think of who needs to call this method. Using a boolean, the caller needs to handle 3 cases: return true, return false (The caller cannot and should not know this is never going to happen) and throw exception. If you don't return the boolean, you just have no exception and exception cases.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't use a boolean flag together with exceptions!** Ask yourself if the caller could expect something other as `true`. The answer is no as in any other case an exception would be thrown. So you will always return true. This doesn't provide any useful information. Even worse, it can lead into a very confusing situation where you return `false` but no exception was thrown (this cannot happen in your example, as yours is very simple, but I just want to elaborate some cases).

Also note that Hibernate itself doesn't return any things by its `currentSession().save(...)` method! I would strongly advise to follow this pattern!

And also note that all kinds of boolean flags, error codes or statuses returned by a method are contrary to throw an exception. You shouldn't mix two of those concepts (don't throw an exception in some cases and return a boolean flag in some other cases)!

Comment: Superb (y) proper design.

Comment: @ThomasUhrig Awesome explanation for the approach

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, hibernate save method returns:
the generated identifier. Would you give me an example that I need to use boolean flan? I am a bit confused. Do you mean in this case, if nothing is thrown I should assume everything was fine? By not mixing two concepts are you referring to whole application or specific methods?

Comment: @DanielNewtown if no exception is thrown in your example, you can be sure that the save operation was successful. By not mixing two concepts I refer to a specific method like the one above and to the whole application. Always use exceptions to handle things which should work but don't do so because of some unexpected circumstances. It will  make your code much cleaner. Error codes might be good for APIs or to hide the real cause. But inside your application go for exception. (IMHO)

Comment: @ThomasUhrig In that case, I should always stick to exceptions. If nothing is thrown I should take that as successful processing am I right?

Answer (score 1):

The absence of an exception should be a success indicator. That is if no exception is thrown the save is successful.So it should be **better if you just call sav**e and dont return true.

But still it is **good to have a boolean indicator** like you already have in your code.

Support at [this  question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422425/best-practice-to-return-a-result-flag-after-saveorupdate-in-hibernate) too

Answer (score 0):

Much better using this method

```
public void saveContact(Contact contact) {  
    currentSession().save(contact);
}
```

Comment: Why? would you elaborate that?

Comment: Daniel Newtown, please, see a wonderful explanation of @ThomasUhrig

Comment: @VirajNalawade HibernateException is descendant of RuntimeException.

Comment: Daniel Newtown, and if you want to see some consistent approach to working with Hibernate you can refer [this](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate)